# Should I write an answer to my own question for future reference to others?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes happened that the answer to a question is very short with some link. The answer solved my problem and I have upvoted and accepted it. But for anyone that will look at this question in the future it may not have the desired quality. So I have written an answer to my own question explaining what I did to solve the problem. Of course, giving the credit to the user whose answer I have followed.

Is this OK to do?

Comment: Yes, no harm in writing your own Q&A , many people do it.

Comment: I think in the example you give it would be good to give the user who provided the link a chance to edit first. If they fixed your issue, they do deserve the credit. Leave a comment and give them some time.

Comment: Very god point @MarkKirby.

Comment: Or edit their answer to improve it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

While answering your own question is indeed both allowed and encouraged, if another user's answer was what enabled you to find the solution, it might be better to simply edit that user's answer instead of posting your own.

Don't get me wrong, there's nothing bad about posting your own if it adds significant details that were lacking in the original answer. It's just extra nice, polite and selfless to edit the other answer instead.

Answer (score 22):

Absolutely you should; [Ask Ubuntu explicitly encourages it](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).